# How do I use a QTableView with a database?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm using a QTableView with an hiden `invoice_id` column to manage invoices row,

I would like to know if there is a way to change the `invoice_id` column value, for each row, before committing.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Do you edit anything for the fields?  What are you committing and how does it relate to QTableView?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use setdata(),here is a little example:

```
model->setData(model->index(row, 1), QVariant(id));
```